# Paypal Website Payments Standard with a Ruby/Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I would like to implement a payment solution with my Rails site using Paypal Website Payments Standard. (See https://www.paypal.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_standard_home.html). I don't want fancy gateways, and I don't want to go through the hassles related to storing credit card information. I also want to use Paypal IPN for notifications.

I have checked out various sites such as http://www.fortytwo.gr/blog/14/Using-Paypal-with-Rails, and I'm too cheap to try Rails Kits at http://railskits.com/saas/.

Does anybody know of a working open-source Rails application that makes use of Paypal Website Payments Standard for billing, and can you point me to that code?

Also, my business is in Canada, but the servers are in the USA. Do I have to sign up for Paypal.com or paypal.ca?

Comment: Spree seems to also have a plugin for this at http://github.com/Gregg/spree-pp-website-standard/tree/master

Comment: I've used ActiveMerchant before with a Ramaze application, and it works, but my comment on that is if you can avoid it, avoid PayPal, as it is confusing and not userfriendly to develop with/for.

Answer (score 18):

I would also check out [ActiveMerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/). Here's a bit more info [here](http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/1/17/paypal-express-payments-with-activemerchant).

Answer (score 4):

Both [Spree](http://spreehq.org/) and [Substruct](http://code.google.com/p/substruct/) are e-commerce platforms written in Rails that support Paypal IPN.  Both are open source, so it might be helpful to start by looking at how they handle Paypal Integration.

Answer (score 3):

How about using this code snippet?

http://cubanlinks.org/articles/2005/8/3/ruby-on-rails-paypal-ipn-code-example

I'd prefer not to use activemerchant or other plugin if I can use this simple code snippet.

Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

[Spree](http://spreehq.org) contains an [extension](http://github.com/Gregg/spree-pp-website-standard/tree/master) for Payapl Website Payments Standard.  In fact, the popular [envycasts](http://envycasts.com) site is a great example of this extension in use.  If you want Rails and you want the Paypal Standard stuff, this is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is much smaller solution, use paypal gem, what it gives is the IPN a very easy IPN handling. All the rest is just an html form :)

Comment: What, exactly is the name of this gem?