# Paypal with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am integrating paypal in my rails app.
I want to know that whose information I should put in billing Address and credit card information? (seller/buyer)
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265765/paypal-website-payments-standard-with-a-ruby-rails-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have got answer.
You can put that information of any person. its just concern with credit card.

Answer (score 2):

To get valid test data you have to create an account in sandbox, and set up a buyer and a seller test account for yourself and use their credentials to test it.

https://developer.paypal.com/

You can find great screencasts about this topic on [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=paypal)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 'active_merchant' (https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant). if so in the 'Sample Usage' it has the details. if not its better to use it :D

cheers

sameera

Comment: I have already shown that. But as I am using paypal services there is something different configuration.
so If u have any answer for that do let me know please.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: 'I have already shown that' , I guess u mean that you are using 'active_merchant' ruby gem for paypal payment processing, if so its README has a section called 'Sample Usage' and there it has a sample configuration. Since you are accepting payments from your customers, details should be buyers