# How to use Paypal Standard in a web application with PHP

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm looking for a way to build a web application using paypal payments standard.  I'd like the user to get redirected to paypal, then fill out their information, and upon completion, add a value in our database saying that they successfully paid.  I haven't found a solution or answer to this.

I found this thread for RoR, but didn't find anything for PHP

[Paypal Website Payments Standard with a Ruby/Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265765/paypal-website-payments-standard-with-a-ruby-rails-application)

Answer (score 2):

You can see instructions for a Payment Data Transfer at [PayPal's site](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer). Basically, you post the transaction amount and an ID token to their site, the customer pays on paypal.com, and then they're sent back to a pre-defined URL on your site with the transaction details.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [NVP API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview) to do that.